# Magento 2 set page title as html

Tags: magento2.2.2, html, page-title

How to set page title to have html on it E.G

```
$this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Your'.html_entity_decode(' <span>Page</span>'). 'Title'));
```

That's ain't working! Anyone know how thanks in advance

Comment: It is your custom module? If not then can you please tell me the path where you are trying. file path

Comment: @RaviSoni I've looked at `.../vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml`  and I can see that `$block->escapeHtml($block->getPageHeading())`  it won't work as it's escaping it so I just overwritten title.phtml in my custom html then remove the `escapeHtml` so I can add html to the title thanks

Answer (score -1):

if you need a page title into the phtml file than just try this below block

```
echo $block->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title')->getPageTitle();
```